# How do I implement a File or Directory filter script in install4j actions, and why does install4j not allow wildcards?

Tags: installation, install4j

I am trying to use the "Set the UNIX access mode of files" built-in action and am finding it a bit difficult.  I basically need to do the following for my app:

```
chmod -f u+x etc/*
chmod -f u+x etc/cli/*
chmod -f u+x etc/callout/*.pl
chmod -fR u+x etc/support/*
```

It appears as though install4j doesn't allow the use of wildcards in this action when selecting files/directories (it also doesn't allow multi select in the file chooser which makes this particularly painful).

I also can't seem to find a bound installer context variable or method to use in the filter scripts.

Two questions really:
1.  Is it possible I'm doing something wrong when trying to use wildcards or are they not supported here?
2.  How do I implement the filter scripts?  Is there a context method to get the file/directory being acted on?

Comment: Figured it out! Unfortunately the documentation is a little sparse in this area, but I found an example on the "What's New in 5.0" page.

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/whatsnew5.html

I hadn't noticed the addition of the "java.io.File file" parameter for this action.

So basically the following works:

file.getPath().endsWith("pl")